# Unable to loop through object of an object of an object in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to loop an object of an object of an object. So basically the object hierarchy is

```
FundClassViewModel
FundDetailsViewModel
FundClassDetailsViewModel
```

I need to print the values of FundClassDetailsViewModel

At the moment I am not getting an error message but neither is it printing the values. I can see only the column headers getting printed

```
<div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel"> 
<!-- <div *ngIf="fundClassKeys">  -->
    <!-- {{fundClassKeys.length}} -->
    <table class="fundClassesTable" id="toggled-element">

        <tr>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Class ID</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Codency Class?</td>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses | keyvalue" class="rowItem">
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass.value.Description}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass.value.Id}}</td>
            <!-- <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem">{{fundClass}}</td> -->
        </tr>


    </table>
</div>
```

FundClass component

```
export class FundClassesComponent implements OnInit {

    //@Input() FundClasses;
    private _fundClasses : any;
    public fundClassKeys = [];


    public get FundClasses(): any {
        return this._fundClasses;
    }
    @Input()
    public set FundClasses(value: any) {
        this._fundClasses = value;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        // if(this.FundClasses) {
        // this.fundClassKeys = Object.keys(this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel);
       // }
    }
}
```

Object structure screenshot

[image]

Json structure

```
{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":5508},{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":5508}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"FundId":237146}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]}
```

Comment: It should be available at `myReponse.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these way

```
<div *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" class="rowItem">
   <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
      <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

[Here stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nejjib)